# tableView imageView content mode not working?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimage, imageview

I Have an image, which is inside of a table row, i'm trying to make it round  by doing height/2

```
cell.imageView.frame.height/2
```

so the problem is that when i'm trying to insert image into a cell, the image doesn't change its size, my code looks like this

```
let named = "avatar.png"
let imageName = UIImage(named: named)
cell.imageView?.image = imageName
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
if(tableArray[indexPath.row] == "avatar"){
    cell.imageView!.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,10,10)
    cell.imageView?.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.imageView?.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cell.imageView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView!.frame.height/2
    cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.imageView?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
}
```

I've tried a lot of suggestions from google, to stackoverflow but couldn't get whats the problem, can anybody help?

Comment: I suspect the size does change, right until the cell lays out it's subViews again. Have you tried using an image view not layed out by the cell, e.g. your own sub view?

Comment: didn't get the question sorry

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the size of imageview present in default UITableViewCell , if you want to change imageview size  then you need to take a custom UITableViewCell .

Comment: Actually, an additional sub view will do, no subclassing needed.